# Netbeans C remote debugger dissasembly view only

Tags: c, linux, debugging, netbeans

I'm trying to debug an embedded board with ARM architecture that runs linux. I'm using NetBeans IDE on a Linux PC to remotely develop the code. I've set everything up according to several guides. Netbeans packs the source files, sends them via TFTP to the board and builds them there executing the board's own toolchain via ssh.

When I try to debug the debugger starts but apparently no line/code information is added to the executable (although it's compiled with -g option and in "debug" mode) so Netbeans jumps to disassembly view where I can set breakpoints and run line by line... in assembly instead of line by line over the source code. If I gdb the executable in the embedded board gdb says it only has source info for one of the files which isn't the one that contains main function but some random one so I can't use GDB either. I've tried creating a new project on a fresh Netbeans installation and the same happens. I can perfectly debug native projects but not the remote ones.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty old question, but... I've been faced with the same pain,
spent a lot of time and couldn't find anything.

My configuration: 
Host - Ubuntu 14.04 with NetBeans 8.0.2.
Client - Ubuntu 12.04 with both g++ 4.6.4 and 5.2.1, gdb 7.4-2012.04

I've found out that NetBeans falls in disassembly mode (mentioned in start topic) with {g++ 5.2, gdb 7.4} tools pair, but work's fine with {g++ 4.6, gdb 7.4}. So gdb 7.8 installation solves issue with g++ 5.2.